# Bind ASP.NET Menu control to XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, menu

I'm trying to bind my own xml file (for some certain purposes i don't want to use a sitemap) to ASP.NET control. I have this code which - with help of some articles I have found - should bind ASP.NET Menu control to xml file, but it doesn't.

Do I miss something?

```
XmlDataSource xmlSource = new XmlDataSource();
xmlSource.DataFile = ResolveUrl("~/menu.xml");
xmlSource.XPath = @"/menu/Items/menuItem";
xmlSource.DataBind();

MenuItemBinding binding = new MenuItemBinding();
binding.DataMember = "menuItem";
binding.NavigateUrlField = "NavigateUrl";
binding.TextField = "Text";

Menu1.DataSource = xmlSource;
Menu1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
Menu1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What does your XML file look like? Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: If you provide the actual XML data, then we can fiddle with it and find out how to make it work. At this point, without the data, we would be guessing mostly.