# ASP.NET menu from XML file , dropdown is on the right, needs to below

Tags: asp.net, xml, menu

I found [Bind ASP.NET Menu control to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382849/bind-asp-net-menu-control-to-xml) question helpful in find my problem. Now the problem I am facing is my menu looks like this (even the main menu as expanding menu attached to it. I want it to have a regular drop down. Can I achieve it?

[image]

My xmlfile is attached. I tried removing the root tag but than it is not a xml file and it breaks the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu>
    <menuItem>
        <text>
            &lt;img align="middle" src="images/new.gif" width="32"
            height="16" /&gt; What's New? &lt;img align="middle"
            src="images/right.gif" width="16" height="16" /&gt;
        </text>
        <subMenu>
            <menuItem>
                <text>&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;New Articles</text>
                <url>/suboption1.1.html</url>
            </menuItem>
            <menuItem>
                <text>&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;New FAQs</text>
                <commandName>NewFAQ</commandName>
            </menuItem>
        </subMenu>
    </menuItem>
    <menuItem>
        <text>
            &lt;img align="middle" src="images/paw.gif" width="20"
            height="16" /&gt; Animal Facts &lt;img align="middle"
            src="images/right.gif" width="16" height="16" /&gt;
        </text>
        <url>/option2.html</url>
        <subMenu>
            <menuItem>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[<img align="middle" src="images/paw.gif" 
              width="20" height="16" /> Animal Facts <img 
              align="middle" src="images/right.gif" width="16" 
              height="16" />]]>
                </text>
                <url>/suboption2.1.html</url>
                <subMenu>
                    <menuItem>
                        <text>Facts about Terriers</text>
                        <url>/suboption2.1.1</url>
                    </menuItem>
                    <menuItem>
                        <text>Facts about Beagles</text>
                        <url>/suboption2.1.2</url>
                    </menuItem>
                    <menuItem>
                        <text>Facts about Great Danes</text>
                        <url>/suboption2.1.3</url>
                    </menuItem>
                    <menuItem>
                        <text>Facts about Poodles</text>
                        <url>/suboption2.1.4</url>
                    </menuItem>
                </subMenu>
            </menuItem>
            <menuItem>
                <text>
                    &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Facts About
                    Goats
                </text>
                <url>/suboption2.2.html</url>
            </menuItem>
            <menuItem>
                <text>
                    &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Facts About
                    Snakes
                </text>
                <url>/suboption3.2.html</url>
            </menuItem>
        </subMenu>
    </menuItem>
    <menuItem>
        <text>
            &lt;img align="middle" src="images/email.gif" width="18"
            height="18" /&gt; Contact
        </text>
        <url>mailto:mitchell@4guysfromrolla.com</url>
    </menuItem>
</menu>
```

Adding Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MainMenu.DataSource = GetSiteMapDataSource("firtmenu.xml");
        MainMenu.DataBind();
    }
}

private XmlDataSource GetSiteMapDataSource(string siteMapFileName)
{
    if (siteMapFileName != string.Empty)
    {
        XmlDataSource xmlSource = new XmlDataSource();
        xmlSource.DataFile = siteMapFileName;
        xmlSource.DataBind();
        return xmlSource;
    }
    else
    { return null; }
}
```

Comment: why not parse the XML with XMLReader and form your menus from that?

Comment: I want a quick solution. I found this and it's got this problem. Can explore other options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks like it is not possible**.

Microsoft at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478963.aspx) says, the XML must have a root element and a proper structure of xml with menu,menuitem,  and  properties.

> The Menu class contains a DataSource property that can accept either a
>   string path to an XML file or an XmlDocument instance that has already
>   loaded the proper XML data. Specifically, the XML data must have a
>   root element of  with an arbitrary number of 
>   elements. Each  element must have a  element that
>   specifies the text to display for the menu item, as well as optional
>    and  elements. If the menu item has a submenu, the
>    element should contain a  element, which, like the
>    element, can have an arbitrary number of  elements.

**Further ...**

I found a similar thread on [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?479481-Skipping-first-node-in-XML-with-Menu-control), who asked the same question. The solution there is using XPATH to filter the result. In my example case, you will use

```
XmlDataSource xmlSource = new XmlDataSource();              
xmlSource.XPath = "/menu/menuItem"; // Notice XPAth filter in this line
xmlSource.DataFile = siteMapFileName;
```

It does filter the XML but it produces more problems. That is

1. The root element is not shown (we need a heading for menu like Edit, File etc)
2. All submenu are automatically expanded. If you hover over it, it will then expand the submenus.

Looks like another poor implementation of Microsoft. It is rather not an implementation but just a bogus do this and that and then result, there is not result.